# Database Scheme of OAuth2.0

Tags: database, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm working on OAuth2 with spring boot. And I need to understand the database schema, mainly

**oauth_access_token**,

**oauth_refresh_token**,

**oauth_client_details**

and what every column means.

And I also want to know how to extract the actual access token form database.

Comment: Are you well acquainted with OAuth 2.0 in general ?

Comment: I'm trying to and have implemented it with Spring boot but I don't understand what each column fields are for. And its mapping with UserDetailsService.

Comment: I suggest you take some time to read about oauth 2 ( without spring boot ), once those concepts are clear, I think you might be able to answer your own question

Comment: Can you tell me some useful links

Comment: This [video] (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996OiexHze0) shoud give you a good overall idea

Comment: Hi, I watched the video but I already know that much about OAuth 2.0. I want to know more about how access tokens are stored in DB, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172561/discussion-between-saurabh-gour-and-shreya).